# A corollary to Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Can i get the answer to the following problem.  I am having a proof, i feel there is something wrong here..Can you please point out!

Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be a simply connected domain, and $\gamma: [0,1]\to D$, be a smooth embedding. Given a continuous  one form $\phi$ along $\gamma$ and $\epsilon >0$, Does there exists a holomorphic function $h$ on some open neighborhood $U$ of $\gamma$, $U\subset D$   such that $|dh-\phi|<\epsilon$.

Suggested Proof:

Without loss of generality we  can assume that $0\notin D$. We can write $\phi= \phi_1 d\zeta$, with $\phi_1$ a continuous function on $\gamma$.   We can uniformly approximate $\phi_1$ by Laurent polynomials of the form $\psi_1(\zeta)= \sum_{-k}^k a_j\zeta^k$. As $0\notin D$, we have $\psi_1(\zeta)$ analytic on some possibly small simply connected subdomain of $D$ which we will denote by $D$ itself.

We know that if D is a simply connected domain and $\psi_1$ is analytic in D, then $\psi_1$ has an antiderivative at all points of D.  Hence take $h(z)= \int \psi_1(\zeta)$ which will be our required holomorphic function.

Comment: You mean open *neighbourhood* of $\gamma$?

Comment: @squark:  Yes i mean open neighbourhood of $\gamma$.

Comment:  There is a theorem of Hartogs Rosenthal which states that any continuous function on a compact subset of measure zero can be uniformly approximated by functions holomorphic in a neighbourhood of 
the compact set .The proof follows fairly immeditely from the Cauchy
Pompeiu formula


Comment: contd:the compact subset is in the plane .

Comment: @Ramachandran sir, thanks for the comment. but sorry i cant see the proof of my question from the Hartogs Rosenthal thm.. .... Main point is: I want approximation of continuous function with holomorphic function... Not with rational function..... With the Hartogs Rosenthal theorem, we can approximate $\phi_1$ with rational function $\psi_1$  but we can't find $h(z)$ as $\psi_$ may have singularity. So basically question is: Can we find a holomorphic approximation. 

Comment:  The arc gamma admits a fundamental system of simply connected neighbourhoods .In your suggested argument how do you show that you can uniformly approximate a continuous function by laurent 
polynomials ?


Comment: how do you show that you can uniformly approximate a continuous function by laurent polynomials ?::: By Stone Weierstrass theorem, we can approximate $\phi_1$ with some polynomial $P(z,\bar{z})$. 

Now $\bar{z}=\frac{z.\bar{z}}{z}=\frac{∣z∣^2}{z}$ This gives $\phi_1 \approx P(z,\frac{|z|^2}{z})=\psi_1(z).$ 

Comment: It still has terms involving zeebar.The proof of hartogs rosenthal is pretty easy .First approximate uniformly on gamma by a smooth defined in a small neighbourhood of gamma ,then apply the Cauchy pompeiu formula to this smooth approximation.This is essentially the original proof .The original paper of Hartogs Rosenthal is in MathAnnalen vol
104 yr 1931 pages 606-610

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case we can find a holomorphic function on the plane that uniformly approximates the
given continuous function .It is a consequence of the following .Suppose K is a compact measure zero subset of the plane whose complement in the plane is connected then every continuous function on K can be uniformly approximated by  entire functions.
   Hartogs-Rosenthal says any continuous function on K can be uniformly approximated by functions holomorphic in a neighbourhood of K.By Runge's theorem, functions holomorphic in a neighbourhood of K can be uniformly approximated on K by entire functions.
    In your case since gamma is an arc its complement is connected .Since it is smooth it has measure zero .

Comment: Thanks for the answer:   But i didn't see this extended version of Hartogs-Rosenthal theorem:  I thought that theorem guarantees for the approximation by RATIONAL function.  It will be very helpful for me if you can provide some reference.  Thanks a lot. 

Comment: Yes but the poles of the rational function are outside a neighbourhood
of gamma .

Comment: May be i am making mistake.. Please have the following example: Take K any smooth curve which doesn't passes through $(0,0)∈\mathbb C$. Take $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$, on K, f is continuous, and $\mathbb C−K$ is connected. But f can't be extended to a entire function.... So the theorem you mention seems to have some problem.

Comment: You are confusing approximation and extension. You can certainly approximate f on K uniformly by polynomials .In your example this is
easy to do directly .

Comment: contd:the polynomials referred to are holomorphic.

Comment: ohh sorry.. i got.. and thanks for the time...